# constraint a value to be repeated up to 3 times in the same column in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

When i am making the table (A) , i want to add a constraint that wont allow to add more than 3 times the same value on the same column .

I thought i would make another column (COUNT) that the user would have to count how many times they gave the value and insert it into the new column and then use this constraint :

```
ALTER TABLE A
  ADD CONSTRAINT A check(COUNT<=3);
```

But that would require too much from the user , and it would probably fail .

Is there an easiest way to do it , that doesn't rely on the user?

Comment: You'd need to write triggers for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three options:

(1) Use a trigger to count the number of values in the column.  This would be an `insert`/`update` trigger that would be sure the 4th value is not added.

(2) Create a user-defined function that counts the number of values in the column and add a `check` constraint to ensure the value is 3 or less.  This is not currently allowed in MySQL but one day it might be.

(3) Add a `counter` column in a parent table and then add a `check` constraint to ensure that the counter is never more than 3.  This also requires `insert`/`update`/`delete` triggers to keep the count up-to-date.

In general, I think I prefer (3) because having the counter in the parent table is often convenient.  And although it uses triggers, the failure logic is clear -- it is not hidden in a trigger, it is in a check constraint.

I should suggest a fourth option.  That is to pre-populate the table with three rows per user.  Then only allow users to update the rows rather than `insert`/`delete`.  This requires a flag to indicate whether the row has a value.

Comment: In MySQL neither user-defined function nor subquery allowed in CHECK - so (1) is the only option.

Comment: @Akina . . . None of the options refers to a subquery in the `CHECK` constraint.  The third option keeps the data up-to-date using triggers.

Comment: You mean that trigger is in child whereas CHECK in parent? I just didn't realize it right away.

Comment: @Akina . . . Yes, that is the last option, which I sort of prefer because the actual check is not done in a trigger.  The trigger is only for maintaining the count.  (I'm not a fan of hidden logic.)